# Bootstrap column col-6 display block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering how properly it should be done to do the example of:

|col-lg-6 list-item| |col-lg-6 contact-form|
|col-lg-6 list-item| | STILL contact form  |
|col-lg-6 list-item| | end of contact form |

To describe the example, I want to put contact which might be the height of 3 list-items (lets not stick to the fixed sizes) The main thing that I don't understand is how to make form put properly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe4En.png)

I was thinking of:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 list-item"></div> <div class="col-lg-6 contact-form"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6 list-item"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6 list-item"></div>
```

But it would just not work, because the rest of col-lg-6 would go inline and the contact form would be broke some how.

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is nest the columns, for example,

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="col-lg-12 list-item"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 list-item"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 list-item"></div>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 contact-form"></div>
</div>
```

Doing this will allow the content in the `contact-form` div to stretch and not mess with the size of the `list items`

Comment: That was definitely what I want. Thank you!